# Передача строк или вызов метода из другого фрагмента

Tags: android-fragment, android, java

Здрасьте.

Объясню суть проблемы. Есть два фрагмента `AddObject`, `LoadObject`
и класс работы с сокетами (tcp).В `LoadObject` происходит соединение с сервером, отправляются сообщения к серверу и т.д.

Вопрос. Как отправить сообщение к серверу через фрагмент AddObject? Возможно ли это сделать через `LoadObject`? Или лучше создавать подключение и в этом фрагменте? ( думаю глупо ).

**LoadObject**:

```
public class LoadObjects extends Fragment {

    private TCPClient mTcpClient;

    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        View myFragmentView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.load_objects,
                container, false);
        new connectTask().execute("");
        if (mTcpClient != null) {
            mTcpClient.sendMessage("Соединение установлено!");
        }
        return myFragmentView;
    } }
```

**AddObject**:

```
public class AddObject extends Fragment {

    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                             Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        View myFragmentView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.add_object,
                container, false);
        Button button = (Button) myFragmentView.findViewById(R.id.button);

        button.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener()
        {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v)
            {
                 //тута
            }
        });
        return myFragmentView;
    } }
```

в `AddObject` можно ли использовать **mTcpClient.sendMessage("");** из фрагмента `LoadObject`??

Comment: А что вам мешает создать экземпляр LoadObject в каком нибудь хранилище и обращаться через него?

Comment: Можно пример? или ссылку?

Comment: или делать все в активити, а фрагменты оставить только как вьюху

Comment: и правда, организуйте методы работы с сокетом в активити, и во фрагменте приводите getActivity() к типу вашей активити, и вызывайте у нее нужные методы